# Is $UL\neq PSPACE$ known?

Tags: space-complexity, hierarchy-theorems

$L\neq DSPACE[\omega(\log n)]$ is known.

Is $UL\neq DSPACE[\omega(\log n)]$ and $UL\neq PSPACE$ known?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\mathbf{UL}$ is contained in $\mathbf{NL}$, which is contained in $\mathbf{DSPACE}(\log^2 n)$ by Savitch's theorem, which is strictly contained in $\mathbf{PSPACE}$ by the space hierarchy theorem, so $\mathbf{UL}$ is strictly contained in $\mathbf{PSPACE}$. It would be surprising if e.g. $\mathbf{UL} = \mathbf{DSPACE}(\log^2 n)$, but I don't think it's known to be false.

Comment: How about $\oplus L$ vs $PSPACE$?

Comment: $\oplus \mathbf{L} \subseteq \mathbf{DSPACE}(\log^2 n)$ as well. One way to prove it is a variation of Savitch's algorithm.

Comment: Posted variant https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/48491/bigger-collapse-and-savitchs-theorem.